# wget - how to reject string from downloading html pages

Tags: wget

I am using the following wget command and it downloads the required files I need except for one thing...

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" --wait=3 --load-cookies cookies.txt --timestamping --recursive --level=2 --convert-links --no-parent --page-requisites --adjust-extension --max-redirect=0 --exclude-directories=blog --reject "*per_page=18.html" --reject "*per_page=36.html" (url here)
```

I want to download files like these:

```
a1546997.html
```

But I don't want to download files like these:

```
a1546997.html?pwd=&per_page=36.html
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to reject downloading the html pages containing the extra stuff at the end.

The main problem is that wget gets stuck retrying and times out on the second types of links because the don't go anywhere - and then wget client gets banned.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the --reject-regex switch of wget. You could probably do something like:

```
wget --recursive --no-parent --reject-regex '[^?]' url
```

Comment: I tried adding --reject-regex '[^?]'   and even --reject-regex "*per_page*" and I can't get the switch to work at all - says something wrong with wget usage.

Comment: Shouldn't the expression be just `\?`, so as to say "reject any URL containing a question mark"? The backslash is needed because `?` is a regular expression meta character.

Comment: Both do work for me whereby `'\?'` needs to be quoted depending on the configuration of your shell (`dash` needs it). What is the output of wget? Is it complaining about the regular expression or something else? Btw do you want to strip off the part after the question mark or want to omit these links entirely?

Comment: I'm using wget 1.13.4 on Ubuntu 12.04. command works without the --reject-regex line - but with any --reject-regex line I get the following:   Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
I can't seem to get the --reject  option to work at all.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong - I'm looking at some regex tutorials and I'm stuck.

Comment: I think I just answered my own question - it seems --reject-regex is not in wget 1.13.4 D'Oh!

Comment: Indeed wget 1.13.4 from ubuntu doesn't know about `--reject-regex`. If you would add `--reject '[^?]*'` the files would be downloaded but removed afterwards which looks precisely what you try to avoid :|

Comment: Well, I'm trying to install wget 1.16 and after following these instructions I still see wget -- version 1.13 -- what am I doing wrong - ready to throw the computer out through the window -- instructions followed on:  http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-wget-1-16-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-debian-jessie-debian-wheezy-and-derivative-systems/  - all steps run to completion but after roboot I still have 1.13 - I've done this about 5 different ways and still the same 1.13.  Help. I'm running ubuntu 12.04 - ran sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade too.

Comment: the mose official way to handle this is either to upgrade your system or to use package sources from _wily_ for example. You could also try to download the _deb_ package from (http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/wget) and install it via `dpkg -i <deb-package>`. If that fails for dependencies - try to rebuild that package if you don't want to reinstall your system.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, pragmatic approach ahead:

```
wget ....
rename 's/\.html\?.*/.html/' *.html*
```

This the Perl's rename command